# Potly on Nodejs - "socket hang up and read ECONNRESET"

Tags: javascript, node.js, plotly

I have some error when use Plotly on Nodejs, can you help me?

I write a demo to generate image from splotly api, every 20 seconds, server will create a chart image. Some images is good, but then throw err as image:

[image]

[image]

My code:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  plotly.getImage(figure, imgOpts, function(error, imageStream) {
    if (error) return console.log(error);
    var time = new Date();
    console.log("1--" + new Date());
    var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(time + '.png');
    console.log("2--" + new Date());
    imageStream.pipe(fileStream);

    //            setTimeout(function(){
    //                console.log("3--"+new Date());
    //                //createPdfkit(time);
    //            },10000);


    //            imageStream.on('end',function(){
    //
    //            });
  });

}, 20000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*ECONNRESET*" in general, means that the connection your making has closed.

I assume that this error is being logged after the `plotly.getImage()`? In this case, you'll need to simply handle the error. `if (error) //don't continue` The reason for the error could be that the image you're trying to get is not there, if it's not handled accordingly by plotly.  You may have better luck posting on plotly's [github issues](https://github.com/plotly/plotly-nodejs/issues).